# Which side does the select take place for graphql?

Tags: security, graphql, apollo-server

Suppose I have this type:

```
type User {
  name: string!
}
```

But the resolver pack back that object:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "topSecretPassword": "123456"
}
```

The graphql client doesn't know how to select the field `topSecretPassword` because It's out the schema. Is the field sent to client-side and dropped? Is the field ignored at the server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GraphQL service only returns the requested fields. If the field is not requested, it won't be in the response. If the field doesn't exist in the schema, then it cannot be requested.

This is true regardless of what's returned in the resolver. The value returned in the resolver is always *coerced* into the appropriate type. In the case of an object type, its individual fields are resolved according to their own resolvers.

For a detailed explanation of how execution works, please refer to the [spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Execution).